# Kotlin sealed class subtyping in Jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson, polymorphism, subtyping, sealed-class

I have following classes:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Speech::class, name = "Speech"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Audio::class, name = "Audio"),
)
sealed class AudioItem

data class Speech(val type: String = "Speech", val contentType: String = "SSML", val content: String) : AudioItem()
data class Audio(val type: String = "Audio", val source: String) : AudioItem()
```

When I try to convert generic `ArrayList`:

[image: ArrayList with items as LinkedHashMaps]

to `AudioItem`

```kotlin
val audio: List<AudioItem> = ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules().convertValue(a)
```

I get:

> Cannot construct instance of `AudioItem` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work when you use `sealed class AudioItem()` (mind the "()"). IntelliJ hints that we can delete "()" but if I do then I can't see any constructor in the "Structure" tab.

Additionally, you don't need to explicitly set the type as in `val type: String = "Speech"`. `@JsonSubTypes` will do that for you.